# Cannot connect to container within compose but host connectivity works

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using the docker compose file

```
  version: '3'
    services:
      sqlserver:
        image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
        ports:
          - 1401:1433
        volumes:
          - ./db:/tmp/data
        environment:
          - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
          - "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD='Password99'"
        command:
          - /tmp/data/run.sh
      api:     
          build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
          depends_on:
                    - sqlserver
          links:
                - sqlserver
          ports:
                - 5000:80
```

With appsettings.json connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Entities": "data source=(local),1401;initial catalog=DB_Test;user id=sa;password=Password99;enlist=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;connect timeout=30;App=EntityFramework"
  },
```

I get the error

> api_1        |       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

A connection from a host running api instance to the sql server instance running in docker-compose works fine, so the SQL instance running in the container is fine.

Can anyone help with connectivity between api & sql inside docker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside docker the hostname for the database will be "sqlserver" not localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: This worked, I had to remove the port number also. Thanks!